# Alternative equivalent fertilizer like dyna gro foliage pro in Australia

Tags: fertilizer

I've been reading the praises and the science behind garden fertilizer Dyna-gro foliage pro. The only thing is the product is not available in Australia and shipping from outside is approx $60, too cost prohibitive.
Is there any equivalent product here in Oz that has a 3:1:2 ratio and contains calcium, magnesium and the microelements? I would like to use such a fertilizer as an all rounder for fruit, veggies and ornamentals on a regular basis.